# I cant hear voices when my R and L balances are set to the same number

Tags: audio, music

I cant hear voices, only background music when my L and R balances are set to the same number. I can only hear them if it is set to different values. Is there any explanation to this?

Comment: What OS? Headphones or speakers? Fancy headphones or speakers? USB, mini-jack or what? What driver? Is the driver aware of the device type (headphones vs speakers)? Is the device connected where rear speakers are supposed to be? Is the issue system-wide? or e.g. in a certain video player? or even in a certain video only? Any audio-enhancing software? Balancing on what level are you talking about (e.g. hardware amplifier, system-wide driver, certain application)? Please [edit] the question and add information.

Comment: The output is out-of-phase and L+R are being sent to a single monaural channel.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you have cross-talk between your L and R channels, and the vocals are out of phase in the two channels (either because of something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_Of_Phase_Stereo) in the original audio data, or because that's just how your sound output works). When the left channel's vocals are a positive voltage, the right chanel's vocals are a negative voltage, and the cross-talk mixes them together, resulting in zero vocals. The other parts of the song aren't exactly the same value on both channels (because they are slightly left or right of center in the stereo audio), so when you add the two channels together you still get some sound.

I've observed this when connecting a set of 4-conductor, TRRS, earbuds with a microphone to an audio connector that was designed for a 3-conductor, TRS, cable. The 4-conductor version is mostly compatible with 3-conductor jacks, but sometimes you get this.

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks details, so this answer is just a guess.

Maybe you're using a sole stereo analog device (speakers or headphones), when your OS is set up to generate more channels, including a center one.

Suppose a certain video with 5.1 audio uses mostly the center channel for voices. The audio driver is able to downmix six channels to stereo, if you tell it to. But if you configure it to work in 5.1 mode and if you don't connect a center speaker, you won't hear voices…

… until you unbalance the whole setup, so the driver shifts the center channel partially to the left or right speaker that is connected.

Check if the driver settings correspond with the number of speakers you have.